# returning difference of two dicts and subtracting its values

Tags: python, dictionary

The following is my code.
I have a list of elements as given in the list [4,5,11,5,6,11]. The resultant output I am expecting is unbalanced elements in the array.

```
from collections import Counter

list_elem = [4,5,11,5,6,11]
dict_elem = dict(Counter(list_elem))
max_val = dict([max(dict_elem.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])])
o={k:v for k,v in dict_elem.items() if k not in max_val or v != max_val[k]}

Expecting o to be {4: 1, 6: 1} not {4: 1, 11: 2, 6: 1}

If the list_elem is [1,5,6,7,1,6,1] then I want the output to be  {5:2,7:2,6:1}
i.e. 3 being the value for the key- 1, and then we need the rest of the values of the keys to have value subtracted from the max, i.e -3
```

Comment: "unbalanced elements in the array" meaning?

Comment: Please use better naming for your values it will help you and others read your code. Also `collections.Counter` would be better than your comprehension for `d` as using count in a comprehension is frowned upon

Comment: Balanced array would be an array containing all elements that appear equal number of times

Comment: By that definition isn't `{4: 1, 6: 1}` still balanced? they both show up once. Please explain more on what unbalanced is.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - Balanced array would be an array containing all elements that appear equal number of times  but there is a catch, we should track the highest value and then spit out the difference.

Comment: I think this sounds like you're coining the names balanced and unbalanced as I'm not finding a good definition out there that matches what you want. Please either break it down more in your question and or show more descriptive examples.

Comment: Could you possibly mean something like this: https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/balanced-array/0 ?

Comment: Not really @Jab

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220054/discussion-between-paddu-and-jab).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a Counter and subtracting it from what it would be balanced:

```
ctr = Counter(list_elem)
bal = Counter(dict.fromkeys(ctr, max(ctr.values())))
o = dict(bal - ctr)
```